# Play2 support for multiple routing for different customers?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

How do I support multiple customer routes with play2?

For example I have this route:

```
/       controller.Default.hi()
/login  controller.Default.login()
/abcde  controller.Default.abcde()
```

What can I do to support these routes?

```
/:clientName/*
```

With the least amount of change to the controllers/templates?

Comment: Preferably no changes to templates :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the "clientName" parameter in every controllers methods.

Comment: But wouldnt that mean that I would have to change the templates and views to go to the correct "clientName" as well?

Comment: What do you have to change based on the "clientName"?

Comment: Accepting as answer because it works, but this it not the solution we went with.